# Filter one mapped collection vs. Map two collections

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a one-to-many relationship with a 'child' entity that can be soft deleted.  I must load a parent instance containing child instances in two different scenarios:

1. Edit scenario: Load all children including those which have been "deleted".
2. View scenario: Load only children which have *not* been "deleted".

I can think of two different ways to implement this in the domain model, and my question is: which way(s) is(are) supported by EF code-first and what's the relative complexity of each?

1. Two mapped collection properties: `IList<Child> Children` and `IList<Child> DeletedChildren`.
2. One mapped collection property `IList<Child> Children` and an `IsActive` property on `Child` for marking children that have not been deleted.  Then for scenario 2 I need to load the parent such that `Children` is filtered to only contain instances that haven't been deleted.

I also would like to mention, in case it matters, that this situation is hierarchical (but only two levels deep).  That is, the children are themselves parents for another "soft delete" situation.